# What are the differences between "dubious" and "incredulous", if any?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, vocabulary

Cambridge Dictionary defines the words in the question as follows:

Dubious:

Definition: feeling doubt or not feeling certain

Examples:

1. These claims are dubious and not scientifically proven.
2. He has been associated with some dubious characters.
3. Ruth Ellis has the dubious (= bad) distinction of being the last woman to be hanged in Britain.

Incredulous:

Definition: not wanting or not able to believe something, and usually showing this

Example: A few incredulous spectators watched on as Paterson, ranked 23rd in the world, beat the champion.

Both words convey a sense of someone not inclined to believe something at face value, but really, are there any differences between these two words?

Comment: Your three examples are for a different sub-meaning of 'dubious' than the definition.

Comment: My father was dubious about my chances of getting into Yale; he was incredulous when I was accepted (invented example; I didn't go to Yale).

Answer (score 2):

If you are dubious about something, you are inclined to doubt it (suspect that it isn't true/reliable).

If you are incredulous about something, you are completely unable to believe it.

*Dubious* has a secondary meaning *morally suspect* - 'dubious characters' or *of doubtful value* - a 'dubious distinction' is  something it's not very desirable to be distinguished for.

Comment: I could say that food from the fridge smelled a bit dubious, so I threw it away. These days I have to recycle it.